# PBS job scheduler and ''error: while loading shared libraries'' in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-14.04, pbs

I have installed Gromacs package on a cluster in my home directory. When I run the Gromacs directly form the terminal, it works; but when I submit a Gromacs job to PBS, it raises the following error: "error while loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
done".
Also I exported the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the PBS file (the following line), but the error still remains.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/`

The `/usr/lib64/` is the path of libblas.so.3.

Any help for resolving this error is strongly appreciated.

Comment: Does running ldconfig fix it?

Comment: If static linking is an option, you can try the cmake option -DGMX_PREFER_STATIC_LIBS=ON, optionally with -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ="-static" as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a very similar problem after the LAMMPS installation/compilation with CMake. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody. Try to sumbit your compilation task as a job to the cluster directly. If the cluster you use uses *modules* system, don't forget to load the corresponding modules (in my case these were cmake and intel64).